# Add cocoapods to tests target too?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have default project template with tests and cocoapods installed (`pod install`). Pods works fine with main target, but when I try to import something in tests, I get something like

`Time.m:11:9: 'NSDate-Utilities.h' file not found`

Does this mean that I should add pods directory to header search path in tests target? Can this be done via cocoapods CLI automatically somehow?

---

That question by suggested link had WRONG answer until yesterday.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ok, there is a simple solution, see answer above to get this working automatically. I had to select `Pods/Pods` configuration file for tests target in project info.

[image: configuration file settings]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It took me some time to find this. Here is it in Xcode 6.1: Your Project → Project (blue icon) from the topleft dropdown menu → Info tab → Configurations.

Comment: This is a bad idea since it could get overwritten on future `pod install`s

Comment: I found that link_with was not enough - and had to have link_with AND manually set the config as described in this answer

Answer (score 38):

What you want to use is [`link_with`](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#link_with) from your `Podfile`. Something like:

```
link_with 'MainTarget', 'MainTargetTests'
```

Then run `pod install` again.

Comment: This command is now outdated.