# Cocoapods With Unit test target issue

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods

I'm using an external lib via cocoapods. When I try to run my unit tests I get

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_APIClient", referenced from:

I read that I have to set the "based on" for the unit tests target to Pods which I did but I still get the error.

Any insight would be lovely. Thanks so much.

Comment: What's in your `Podfile`?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512792/libraries-not-found-when-using-cocoapods-with-ios-logic-tests/17885961 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850261/add-cocoapods-to-tests-target-too/17861169

Comment: Is your main target a dependency for your Unit Test target?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I just had to add libpods.a to the test project and it worked. Thanks guys!