# Cocoapods Test Target Header file not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xctest

So I have followed both answers here :
[Add cocoapods to tests target too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850261/add-cocoapods-to-tests-target-too)

And still I can't build for my test cases. My podfile looks like this :

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

link_with 'EReaderDemo', 'EReaderDemoTests'
pod 'KissXML'
pod 'zipzap'
```

After running `pod install`, I had to "${PROJECT_DIR}/Pods" in my main target's User Header Search Path to fix my main target's build and now I can include "ZZarchive.h" file.

But when building the test case demo, I have a Header file not found on "ZZArchive.h" even though I have set the User Header Search Paths, and I have also st the based on configuation file for both targets.

Comment: I've recently updated the zipzap podspec so things may have changed. Typically the #include style is `#include <zipzap/zipzap.h>` -- did this not work?