# CocoaLumberJack XCTest Linker Error when running test cases

Tags: ios, xctest, cocoalumberjack

When using CocoaLumberJack with XCTest, I get an error that it cannot find the `DDLog.h`. I've tried changing it to `<CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h>` with no luck. The project compiles and runs fine with LumberJack working in the iOS Simulator, but when I run it for the unit testing target, I get this error (See Screenshot).

Here is my -Prefix.pch

```
  #import <Availability.h>

  #ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
  #warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
  #endif

  #ifdef __OBJC__
      #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
      #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
      #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
      #import <CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h>
      #import "Utilities.h"
  #endif


  #ifdef DEBUG
  static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
  #else
  static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_ERROR;
  #endif
```

Error:

[image: Error]

I've linked the libraries to to the `tests` target also as shown below with the `libPods.a`.

[image: Linked Libraries]

Why won't LumberJack link properly when running the TestCases? Is there something else I need to add to the TestTarget for it to link properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the customizations to the `-Prefix.pch` file and reformat the `podfile` to use targets. I had to move the

```
 #import "DDLog.h"
```

and

```
#ifdef DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_ERROR;
#endif
```

into a `Utility.h' class.

The `podfile` was rebuilt to link both targets:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

def common_pods
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'HexColors'
end

target :MyApp do
    common_pods
end

target :MyAppTests do
    common_pods
end
```

I also had to remove the `libPods.a` from both targets since it would no longer be built. Instead `libPods-MyApp.a` and `libPods-MyAppTests.a` are built with the new `podfile` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `Pods` configuration in your project → project settings → info → configurations:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850444/511878